# Is the USA able to place a full-fledged sanction on China as they did in the case of Russia?

Tags: united-states, china, sanctions

- [China's Foreign Minister Wang Yi visits Iran](https://youtu.be/NjrKiBmgd9c)

Say, the aforementioned $400 billion deal between China and Iran goes through.

Is the USA able to place a full-fledged sanction on China as they did in the case of Russia?

This is neither a hypothetical question nor an opinion-based question. I want to know if the USA has the capability to put sanctions on a Russian scale on China and if the US economy is able to sustain the aftermath of the sanction on China.

Comment: Most sanctions against Russia were targeted at particular individuals and a few companies, rather than the country or the people. Ironically, in response to those targeted sanctions, Russia has enacted  "anti-sanctions" that hit its own citizen (e.g. bulldozed and banned European food.)

Comment: VtC: "if the USA has the will" is a question about motivations, which can't be answered until something happens.

Comment: @JohnDallman, changed the word.

Comment: This is a controversial topic that almost not possible to offer a concrete answer. Also, although the claim of the question is non-opinion based, you have offered your own without the backup of data and relevant documentations. I voted to keep this post closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A (very) qualified 'Yes'**

There are actually two things to consider, first *direct* sanctions by the US against China, and second *indirect* sanctions through third parties, either because they have been convinced to go along or because they have been pressured to go along.

- Unilateral sanctions are not much different from the 'trade wars' we have seen time and again. The US government tells US consumers and companies that they can't have certain Chinese goods, or that they are to pay a penalty if they want them. (Some politicians tell their people that it is the other side who pays the price, but that very much depends on the market conditions.)
- Multilateral sanctions are also going on, to some degree. The US tried to convince and pressure other countries not to buy Chinese [5G telecommunications hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei#U.S._business_restrictions), and many countries went along. In some cases they US went well beyond a mere boycott, and in some cases it was able to carry that off, like the [Banco Delta Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Asia_Financial_Group) case.

There is a debate in the comments if this is an opinion-based question. To some degree it is, but it is possible to look at the price the US would have to pay for "comprehensive" sanctions against China -- it is much higher than the price for "comprehensive" sanctions against Russia or North Korea, that's for sure.

Comment: "Price to pay" is always the unsettled arguments (opinion based), especially in the eyes of the policy maker, on his ability to convince his voters for the cost-benefit calculation.

Comment: @r13, I think I don't need sources to show that the disruption from comprehensive sanctions between the US and China will be greater than the disruption from comprehensive sanctions between the US and Russia or Iran. Yet the US did not manage to forge such sanctions against Russia, they did better against Iran until the previous administration disrupted that. That's not hard numbers, just a relative size estimate.

Comment: The post is closed for a reason, the question involves policies, which always change with changing situations, and always have more than two sides to each policy, thus opinions.

Comment: @r13, current or changing situations as such are not off-topic. It is the unfounded speculations about internal motivations which create the problem.

Comment: Unless you have solid evidence, or direct measure, how can you pin a country's "ability", or capability" in doing something like this. Both the question and the answer are pure speculation, and opinion based.

Comment: Also, do you expect the administrations under Trump (or Bush) and Biden (or Obama), will provide a definite, coherent answer to this question?

Comment: @r13, China is the largest trading partner of the US, Russia is 18, Iran is 202. I consider that coherent even if it isn't definite.

Comment: Trump treated China as enemy, a country of thieves; Biden is much considerable, but still see China as competitor rather than partner. The partnership has yet to come, on clean air, human rights ... issues. Too early to tell.

Answer (score 0):

The USA engineered a cold war against the former Soviet Union based upon the propaganda of the communist threat. It was for this reason that they pressured the judges at the Nuremberg Trials not to go after the capitalists that had finded the Nazi regime even though they had explicitly said before-hand that prosecutions wouldn't be limited to the military and political administration, but also the financial administration.

This led to a policy of 'containment' which eventually forced the breakup of the former Soviet Union. It's unlikely that anything on this scale will happen with the current sabre rattling between the USA and its satellites against China, simply because one would expect China to have learnt vicariously from recent geo-political history and refuse to be drawn into an unwinnable cold war.

Whilst there have been sanctions by the USA against China, for example, at the inception of the People's Republic of China, after the Tiannamen Square Massacre and more recently, Trumps administration sanctioned Huawei and subsidiaries and mandayed visa restrictions against senior political figures in China for the Uighur muslim human rights scandal, these pale in comparison to what was done against the former Soviet Union during the 'red scare'.

Moreover, China is integrated into the world economy in a way that the Soviet Union was not; not only from the size of their own economy, but also with their Road  & Belt initiative dating from a decade ago where they they invested in infrastructure in over 70 countries, covering 65% of global population and as of 2017, accounted for 40% GDP. It's widely recognised as one of the largest infrastructure projects in history - Keynianism writ large. It's unlikely that many third countries will be swayed by USA propaganda against China, though one will certainly expect some symbolic moves from it's traditional allies: for example, the recent sanction by the USA in March of this year against two Chinese officials and coordinated with the EU and Canada, again for the Uighur muslim human rights scandal.

Comment: I don't want to make a bigger argument than I can handle, but to point out the internal stability of Communist China has been hinged on the rapid growth of personal wealth in the few decades past. Where was the fuel came from for the growth? IMO, looking West, not the third word countries, which relied heavily on China's handout.

Comment: @r13: For sure, but it wasn't through altruism, the West was looking for a cheaper region to produce its goods. Hence the deindustrialisation of the UK and the USA with much cheaper - for the employers - service labour - and damn the unionised labour of the pre-neoliberal era. Recall the union busting efforts of the two architects of neoliberalism - Thatcher and Reagan. It's meant the precaritisation of the general populace where automation is now encroaching on the middle-class. One of the effects of neoliberalism was the loosening of capital controls, so capital searched for a large pool ...

Comment: @r13: ... of cheap labour - China.

Comment: IMO, the brewing problem that worries the China government, if facing a stiff sanction, is too many of the past "cheap labors" have moved up and wanted more. Similar to take the candy away from a spoiled kid, unexpected outcome could happen. Unlike N Korean, who have nothing to lose, since they've never had any. I don't know Russian though.

Comment: @r13: I would have expected that they have planned for such a contingency, after all, it's happened in many other places. But it seems with their Belt & Road Initiative they are planning to replicate their success on the global stage, after all, they have lifted 750 million out of poverty, an unprecedented feat. I don't think it's wrong for a more educated, a more resourced and resourceful population to make demands. That is what freedom amd emanicipation entails. Imagine if the USA had spent what it has done on its militarised empire-building on a similar initiative, that is on ...

Comment: @r13: ... on infrastructure, rather than a thousand military bases dotted around the world, what the world would now be like.

Comment: "Freedom", that's exactly the last thing the China government willing to give to his people,

Comment: @r13: I think a lot of freedom comes from simply not being poor. As you're interested in 'spoiled' people, have you considered what it means to be 'spoilt' by poverty and oppression? This is the lot of many peoples in the global south which China is attempting to alleviate through it's reconstruction efforts.

Comment: In a sense you are correct. So facing a fierce economic sanction, the vast majority of Chinese people stand to lose the most - wealth, freedom (as you defined), then faith. Not a good sign for the government does not want to lose control.